# Kendoui cannot locate dejavu fonts after publish to IIS

Tags: javascript, css, iis, kendo-ui, telerik

I tried to replicate this [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout).

In my BundleConfig.cs:

```
<!-- language: c# --> 
public static string KendoVersion = "2015.1.429"; 
public static string KendoTheme = "bootstrap"; 
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/kendoui").Include(
    String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common.min.css",KendoVersion),
    String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.core.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme),
    String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.min.css", KendoVersion,KendoTheme),
    String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.{1}.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme)
 ));
```

I have this simple view:

```
<div class="pdf">
    Test <strong>Test2</strong>
</div>

<button class="export-pdf k-button" onclick="getPDF('.pdf')">Esporta in PDF</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPDF(selector) {
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(selector)).then(function (group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Richiesta.pdf");
        });
    }
</script>
```

If I run my application in the local environment I don't have any problem. But if I publish to IIS, in remote, when I click on "PFD" button I have this JavaScript error:

> Cannot load font from  myWebSite.it/TestPdf/Content/kendo/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf

The files are correctly pulished in the server and correct path is:
"~/Content/kendo/**2015.1.429**/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf"

If I copy the folder fonts inside folder "~/content/kendo" it works.

**QUESTION**

Why does the application have this behaviour?

Did I miss some configurations somewhere?

Comment: what is the folder 2015.1.429 for?

Comment: Are you using bundling?

Comment: @gaynorvader the folder 2015.1.429 was created when i converted my project in a Telerik MVC project. "2015.1.426" is the version of Telerik that i'm using.

Comment: @ASG yes. I use bundling but i didn't declare the fonts Dejavu nowhere. I supposed that the function "kendo.drawing" automatically knew where is the font.

Comment: @jebbo can you put your css bundle code up from BundleConfig.cs. I think you might be missing the version in the bundle

Comment: @ASG in my BundleConfig.cs i call for example:

<!-- language: c# -->
`public static string KendoVersion = "2015.1.429";

public static string KendoTheme = "bootstrap";
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/kendoui").Include(
String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common.min.css",KendoVersion),
String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.core.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme),
String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme),
String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.{1}.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme)));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that fonts (and images) are relative to the css file so when it bundles it's looking for the fonts in the wrong path, so it's trying to find fonts in ~/Content/kendo/fonts but they aren't there as they are in ~/Content/kendo/2015.1.429/fonts

Change your bundle to include the version so it can find the fonts folder in the correct path e.g.

```
string bundleName = string.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendoui", KendoVersion);
 bundles.Add(
            new StyleBundle(bundleName).Include(
                String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common.min.css", KendoVersion),
                String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.core.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme),
                String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.common-{1}.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme),
                String.Format("~/Content/kendo/{0}/kendo.{1}.min.css", KendoVersion, KendoTheme)));
    }
```

It works when in debug as it probably isn't optimizing them and thus is using the correct paths

This has more information http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#css-bundling

Comment: Thank you @ASG. I see that the fonts are declared in:
kendo.common.min.css and in kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css.
I resolved converting the declaration of these css with the asolute path.

Comment: Is it possible to change the where it looks for the fonts dynamically?

Comment: I'd like to know if this is configurable as well.  It is seriously a pain to pull in that version number in order to include the bundle using Scripts.Render in the layout file.  Plus we prefer to use fake paths and bundle other libraries in order to obfuscate our application